# Is this a good way to "get rid of the sprite shakes" for my sprites that "target" other sprites? (XNA)

Tags: xna, 2d, sprites

I'm relatively new to XNA, but very proficient with C#. I want to know if this is the best way to solve the sprite shaking problem. I had a sprite class that can target a place/other sprite on the map and follow it.

Here's my update method:

```
public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        //move this rectangle closer to the target
        float EntitySpeed = 100f; //this is actually a property
        Vector2 velocity = new Vector2();
        if (_target.GetX() < this.GetX())
            velocity += new Vector2(-1, 0) * EntitySpeed;
        if (_target.GetX() > this.GetX())
            velocity += new Vector2(1, 0) * EntitySpeed;
        if (_target.GetY() < this.GetY())
            velocity += new Vector2(0, -1) * EntitySpeed;
        if (_target.GetY() > this.GetY())
            velocity += new Vector2(0, 1) * EntitySpeed;

        //a guy on pluralsight said it's best to update velocity taking a time into consideration to account for faster/slower computer speeds
        var movement = (velocity * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds);
        _position += movement; //position is a Vector2


        //is the code below a good solution to get the sprite to stop shaking?
        //if we're "close" to the target sprite, then set the position exactly
        Vector2 vectorDiff = this._position - new Vector2(_target.GetX(), _target.GetY());

        bool xReached = Math.Abs(vectorDiff.X) <= Math.Abs(movement.X);
        bool yReached = Math.Abs(vectorDiff.Y) <= Math.Abs(movement.Y);

        if (xReached)
            _position.X = _target.GetX();
        if (yReached)
            _position.Y = _target.GetY();

    }
```

Comment: What is the problem if you set the position when it gets close?

Comment: @Jon I guess a downside I can think of would be that something could be say 16 pixels away from the target. it travels 15, but then it's close so it gets a little extra "help" to move another pixel.  I guess I'm thinking that this has to be a pretty common problem in the game development world and wondered if there's a best practice to solve it.

Comment: it might be that the timing makes setting the position so trivial that it's not worth worrying over the precision.

Comment: It depends on your implementation.  You could always just stop moving it when the entity gets in a specific range.  Another option, would be to calculate the maximum vector you can translate to not overshoot your target, then clamp to that maximum.